# Presto on AWS EMR: access via Hue

Tags: classpath, emr, hue, presto

In a Hue notebook (AWS EMR v5.5), when trying to use Presto, a CLASSPATH error is encountered.

Logs:

```
File "/usr/lib/hue/build/env/lib64/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'CLASSPATH'
```

Information about exporting CLASSPATH to avoid this error is provided here:
[Integrating JDBC-compatible databases](http://gethue.com/custom-sql-query-editors/)

But the error is still encountered (after export CLASSPATH and restart of Hue service on the Master node).  Anyone encounter this and find a fix?  Please share.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the same issue as https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-5859